# Angularjs Directive For jQuery Cycle Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

I built the site with AngularJs and JQuery Cycle Plugin. Everything was working great until I needed to move my html partials into separate folders. Now when I run my code I see the jQuery  Cycle plugin stopped working. Googling around and I found that I need to create a directive that would preserve the jQuery Cycle functionality, but I have no Idea how to create a directive that would make my  jQuery Cycle plugin work in an Angular Site.

Below is how it is in jQuery code and working condition

```
$(".items").cycle({  
fx:     'scrollHorz', 
speed:  'slow', 
timeout: 1000, 
next:   '.move-left',  
prev:   '.move-right' 
        });
```

And this one is a broken one which doesn't work using directive approach.

```
myAngularApp.directive('cycle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           $(".items").cycle({  
            fx:     'scrollHorz', 
            speed:  'slow', 
            timeout: 1000, 
            prev:   '.move-left',  
            next:   '.move-right' 
        });
        }
    };
});
```

**Can someone tell me how to create a directive that would make Cycle plugin work in an Angular Site?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You code should work with some little modifications:

```
myApp.directive('cycle', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       $(element).cycle({
           fx: 'fade',
           timeout: 10
       });
    }
  };
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WK2Fg/1/

Comment: Thanks, I would give that  a try. Just FYI the images I have in my code are also populated from Angular using <img ng-src="{{imageSource}}" /> as against your static images. Thats shouldn't be   a problem, Right?

Comment: @mike: Yes that should not be a problem.

Comment: I noticed this doesn't work if the cycled elements are populated with ng-repeat

Comment: Thats because your directive executes before ng-repeat is compiled. To fix this issue, you can set more priority on above directive than ng-repeat. ngRepeat has priority 1000 so if you use 1001 for your directive, it should work seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of jquery cycle with ng-repeat: http://jsfiddle.net/9dGGb/1/.

I had to wrap the jquery cycle initialization in a setTimeout, because it doesn't work even if the priority is > 1000:

```
myApp.directive('cycle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1001,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           setTimeout(function(){
               $(element).cycle({
                   fx: 'fade',
                   timeout: 10
               });
           }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Stefano, setTimeout should be completely avoided when using Angular. Angular provides the $timeout service for the same purpose (but your hunch was correct, that should effectively solve the problem with the ng-repeat issue :) )

Comment: I had the same problem a while back but got around it by instead wrapping it with `if ($scope.$last) { }` but I'm not sure if that's better or worse than $timeout.